# why can't I bind this xml to the DataGrid?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datatable, mxml

I request some XML with an HTTP-service that looks like this:

```
<s:HTTPService id="flickrCall" url="{api_request}" resultFormat="e4x" result="Alert.show('Success');" fault="Alert.show('error');"/>

<rsp stat="ok">
    <photos page="1" pages="46" perpage="100" total="4501">
        <photo id="7583616364" owner="92677738@N00" secret="17ce853221" server="8421" farm="9"         title="Jack White iii" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
        <photo id="7515807120" owner="47494725@N07" secret="66fcf2cfd5" server="7137" farm="8" title=".- / -.. ..- -.. . / .- - / .- .--. .--. .-.. . -... . . ..." ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
        <photo id="7465794324" owner="73420073@N07" secret="dd42ea30f0" server="7254" farm="8" title="Project 366 175: June 24th" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
        ...
    </photos>
</rsp>
```

I try to bind it to a data-grid like this:

```
 <s:DataGrid id="flickrFotoCollection" width="100%" dataProvider="{flickrCall.lastResult.photo}">
     <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@id"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@title"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="@owner"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

But nothing shows, even though the request has been successfully made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataProvider should be an XMLListCollection, like this:

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{ new XMLListCollection(flickrCall.lastResult.photos.photo)}">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dataProvider="{flickrCall.lastResult.photos}"
```

This should send the grid an array of <photo> tags.

Comment: Have you set the `resultFormat` of your HTTP service to `e4x`?

Comment: Yes, added it to the question.

Comment: Two guesses dataProvider="{flickrCall.lastResult.photos.photo}" or dataProvider="{flickrCall.lastResult..photo}"